# jQuery Datepicker UI close only on click of close button or done button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I am using jQuery UI Datepicker,..

Datepicker works fine but it gets closed when we click outside of the calender or when we click the <kbd>Escape</kbd> button. But I want my date picker to be closed only when we click The done button.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,

    onclose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm', new Date(year, month, 1)));
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This solution has also been posted in [jquery DatePicker Done button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620540/jquery-datepicker-done-button/18267611#18267611), and **it works perfectly:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy'
    }).focus(function() {
        var thisCalendar = $(this);
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
        $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

and **HTML:**

```
<label for="myDate">Date :</label>
<input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker">
```

See how it's working in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmnasim/JLydp/).

**Source:** http://develop-for-fun.blogspot.com/2013/08/jquery-ui-datepicker-month-and-year.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no control over the triggers to close the datepicker. The closest you can get is probably create an inline datepicker and show/hide at your will. But then, the "Done" button is not presented in the inline datepicker, as the inline datepicker doesn't normally need to be hidden. Here's the closest I got, without getting to hacky:

http://jsfiddle.net/william/c8Kcs/1/

HTML:

```
<input id="date" /> <button id="done">Done</button>
<div class="date-picker"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".date-picker").hide().datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    altField: '#date'
});

$('#date').click(function() {
    $(".date-picker").show();
    $('#done').show();
});

$('#done').hide().click(function() {
    $(".date-picker").hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
​
```