# jquery DatePicker Done button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any way to handle the event of pressing the "done" button in jquery UI DatePicker?

I have a datepicker that allows only to choose between year and month as in [here](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-only-month-and-year-in-jquery-ui.html)

The problem is that using the onclose event prevents me from clearing the field (if I click the datepicker pops up then if I close the current selected month and year are put into the field).

I would like not to use an additional "clear" button outside the datepicker, so I though I could use the Done button.

Answer (score 9):

I found solution on one forum (can't remember where - sorry). I know it's been a while, but for future search :)

Note: The change needs to be done in the plugin. You can simply search for "onClose:" to find it.

```
onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
    function isDonePressed() {
        return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
    }
    if (isDonePressed()){
        alert('done pressed');
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is expression that take into account the _esc_ keystroke: `($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-close.ui-state-hover').length > 0) && !inst._keyEvent`

Answer (score 8):

As "Done" button calls _hideDatepicker function, you can override it:

```
jQuery.datepicker._hideDatepicker = function() {
  alert('hello');
};
```

Answer (score 7):

**Here is the perfect solution:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy'
    }).focus(function() {
        var thisCalendar = $(this);
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
        $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

and **HTML:**

```
<label for="myDate">Date :</label>
<input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker">
```

See how it's working in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmnasim/JLydp/).

**Source:** http://develop-for-fun.blogspot.com/2013/08/jquery-ui-datepicker-month-and-year.html

**Courtesy:** [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only/2209104#2209104) and [THAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only/13607884#13607884) SO answers were combined to make this solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#start_date_download').datepicker({
    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    "autoclose": true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: 'Clear' 
}).focus(function() {
    var thisCalendar = $(this);
    $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
        $.datepicker._clearDate($('#start_date_download'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
$('#myInput')
    .datepicker({
        // datepicker options
    })
    .datepicker('widget')
    .find('.ui-datepicker-close')
    .on('click', function () {
        // done button's handler here
    });
```